# Accessing DOM elements within a Handlebar template

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

This must be simpler than I'm making it out to be.  Not sure what's going on.

I have a DIV that I'm "filling" with a Handlebar template.  Once the template is generated, I use a jQuery slideDown to open the panel to view the contents.  Now I need to put a close function to slideUp the DIV.

I think the problem is the click function isn't getting bound because the a.close element is within a script tag.

Here's the DIV for the content:

```
<div id="characteristic" style="bottom:0px; width:800px; display:none; position:fixed; left: 350px;"></div>
```

Here's the jQuery snippet. This is at the top of the HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("a.close").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#characteristic").slideUp();
  });
});
```

And a snippet of the template:

```
<script id="ac-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="holder" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <div class="frame">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="info-box-holder">
                    <a class="close" href="">&times;</a>
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h2>ACTIONABLE CHARACTERISTIC</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-box">
                        <a href="#"><img class="alignleft" src="{{image_large}}" alt="" width="400" height="400" /></a>
                        {{#if subcategory_name}}
                            <h2>{{subcategory_name}}: {{name}}</h2>
                        {{else}}
                            <h2>{{category_name}}: {{name}}</h2>
                        {{/if}}
```

Comment: Where is the characteristic-ID?

Comment: Maybe you need to run the code that is in your ready function after the template has been rendered, as the controls may not exist during onload

Comment: @Amberlamps I have added the the code for the DIV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question and you've probably already worked out the answer, but yes, it's because at the time that your JS code runs, `a.close` does not exist in the DOM.

You need to either run the JS code after handlebars has finished rendering the template, or bind to a higher level DOM element that exists on page load (a container of some sort) and then activate only for the link that you want. Something like this ([see the API](http://api.jquery.com/on/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("#mycontainerdiv").on('click', 'div.info-box-holder a.close', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#characteristic").slideUp();
  });
});
```